# What happened to Version 3 of OJS (Open Journal System)?

Tags: software-distribution, ojs

I am soon starting to develop a website with OJS (Open Journal Systems) and was wondering if anyone knows what happened to the Version 3 branch of the software. Since there is no information online, does anyone have more insights on if there will ever be a version 3 existing?

According to the website of the public knowledge project the last (alpha) version of the development branch (3.X) was released on August 15 2013, while the last stable release (2.X) is from March 17, 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we're just finishing up OJS 3.0 beta, for release a bit later this August. Watch for the release to pop up on our support forum at http://forum.pkp.sfu.ca/ and feel free to contact the team there.